# How to a create dynamic button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a dynamic button using `onclick` function, I have created this simple button. And I want to change the 'id' of the button when it is clicked once. When it is clicked the second time, I want to get the first id back. So I will able to apply two CSS for different styles.

I have changed once the 'id' but how can I get first 'id' back when button is clicked the second time?

```js
function change_style() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id-1");
  x.id = "id-2";
}
```

```css
#id-1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

#id-2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="change_style()"
  id="id-1">Button</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you switch css classes instead of the id? You have to keep track of the previous id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` and toggle class on `button` click.

```js
function change_style() {
      var x = document.getElementById("id-1");
      x.classList.toggle('btn2')
      }
```

```css
.btn1{
    width: 80px; height: 50px; background-color: red; color: #fff;
    }
   .btn2{
    width: 80px; height: 50px; background-color: pink; color: #000;
    }
```

```html
   

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>

    <button type="submit" onclick="change_style()" id="id-1" class="btn1">Button</button>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Md Junaid for your help...!!

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute should be used to identify the element. The `class` attribute can also serve this purpose but ids are unique.

With classes however, you can create states in CSS. For example a normal button has the color red and a button with a certain class added to it has different color, depending on the CSS styles.

In JavaScript you can control which of these styles should be applied to the element by adding or removing a class from the element that you wish to change.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('dynamic-button');

function changeButtonStyle() {
  button.classList.toggle('styled');
}

button.addEventListener('click', changeButtonStyle);
```

```css
/* Default styling without a class */
#dynamic-button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Styles with the class added. */
#dynamic-button.styled {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button id="dynamic-button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the button to the function as 'this':

```
onclick="change_style(this)"
```

Then change the ID from 1 to 2, or 2 to 1.

```js
function change_style(button) {

  // extract number from button
  const idNum = Number(buttonid.split('-')[1]);
  
  // determine new ID number
  const newNum = (idNum === 1) ? 2 : 1;
  
  // set button's new ID
  button.id = 'id-' + newNum;
}
```

```css
#id-1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

#id-2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="change_style(this)" id="id-1">Button</button>
```

Although if you're only changing the style of the button, this is better handled with `class` than `id`.

Answer (score 0):

So u can use getAttribute

```js
function change_style() {
  const x = document.querySelector('button')
  let  val = x.getAttribute('id')
  x.id = val === 'id-1' ? 'id-2' : 'id-1'
}
```

```css
#id-1{
width: 80px; height: 50px; background-color: red; color: #fff;
}
#id-2{
width: 80px; height: 50px; background-color: pink; color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>
<body>

<button type="submit" onclick="change_style()" id="id-1">Button</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers explained everything but I have a little verbose way of solving your problem.

How we can achieve?
You can add a class to the button as you want to change the id of the button and it is impossible to get the button back once the id got changed so instead of using document.getElementById("id") we will be using document.querySelector(".class")

In the above way if we change the id of the button then also we will get the button back and we get do whatever we want with it.

Now coming back to your question:

```
 <button type="submit" class='Btn_1' onclick="change_style()" id="id-1">Button</button>
```

```
function change_style(){
  let btn = document.querySelector('.Btn_1')
    console.log(btn.id)
  if(btn.id === "id-1"){
    btn.id = "id-2"
  }else if(btn.id === "id-2"){
    btn.id = "id-1"
  }

}
```

Like I told you this is a verbose way instead of toggling it we are using this to make you understand what's happening and how the id is getting changed.

In the above code, we are using if statement and checking if that id exists if true then change to id2 else get back the first one.

Hope you found this useful.